# How to calulate xml parsing time in actionscript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I want to calculate the parsing time....

package 
    {

```
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;


    public class Graph extends MovieClip
    {
        private var xmlFile:XML;
        private var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader  ;


        public function Graph()
        {
            loadXML();
            // constructor code
        }

        private function loadXML(file:String="xml/Employee.xml"):void
        {
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(file));
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,parseXML);
        }
        private function parseXML(ev:Event):void
        {
            xmlFile = new XML(ev.target.data);
            ParseTeam2(xmlFile.children()[0]);


        }
        function ParseTeam2(bookInput:XML):void
        {

            trace("XML Output");
            trace("------------------------");
            trace(bookInput);
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var startTime:int = getTimer();

//parse xml...

trace("time passed: " + (getTimer() - startTime) + ", ms");
```

Comment: in this which package i have to import?

Comment: import flash.utils.getTimer; - but keep in mind that results may vary when timing functions.